# Rails - Valid Image. If Valid, capture only name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Currently I am only allowing Users to insert links to external images. Due to this, anything that references the asset pipeline breaks if the user puts in a fake url like '1'.

I fixed this on the view level by using this helper

```
def remote_image_exists?(url)
    url = URI.parse(url)
    http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
    http.use_ssl = (url.scheme == 'https')

    http.start do |http|
      return http.head(url.request_uri)['Content-Type'].start_with? 'image'
    end
  end
```

But this doesn't fix it during submission (I will likely use this helper within form submission at well).

I'm trying to find the appropriate way to do this (If there is?) And then once the link is valid, is there a way to get it's 'current' name? For instance, the name of the natural file? (AKA If I download it, the name the file gets by default).

**Final Result**

Thanks to the chosen answer I was able to decide on the logic I wanted to use.

```
  def remote_image_exists?(url)
    url = URI.parse(url)
    http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
    http.use_ssl = (url.scheme == 'https')

    http.start do |http|
      return http.head(url.request_uri)['Content-Type'].start_with? 'image'
    end
  end

  def get_file_name(url)
    if remote_image_exists?(url)
      current_name = File.basename(URI.parse(url).path)
      return current_name
    else
      return nil
    end
  end
```

Since the need is two-sided, I didn't want to lump it into a singular method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first problem, you're on the right track. Call your helper as part of a [custom validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods) after the user submits the link to get UI level validation before making the server do any real work.

Your helper already contains part of the solution for the second problem. Using the File library, you can extract the file's [basename](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/File.html#method-c-basename) from a URL like so:

```
current_name = File.basename(URI.parse(url).path)
```

One thing you might want to modify in your helper, however, is use of a local variable called `url` and a method arg called `url` for the sake of clarity and in case you want to use the passed in arg a second time within a method.

Comment: Thanks for this information. That is helpful. You providing this, however, led to me drastically changing the scope of my question (Rather how to implement your suggestion). If you could review it, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Please, please don't change your questions like that. Stack Overflow is based on a "one question, one accepted answer paradigm," which means that it's very poor at handling follow-on questions, and questions that have been edited in such a way as to render the answers more or less meaningless. It's asking a bit too much for people who volunteer their time to hit a moving target for you. If you have more questions, simply post them as separate questions. Also, read about the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Have careful think about what you really want before pulling others in to help.

Comment: That's fair. I will re-purpose my question, and mark it as complete.

Comment: Once you've had a good think and isolated the core issue, I'll check in with you. Keep in mind though, that same "one question, one accepted answer" paradigm means that SO is also poor at general discussions. People really want to see questions boiled down to a specific technical issue, so your architectural approach has to be pretty much nailed down before you can ask a really good question -- this is the main reason I'm suggesting you play out the scenarios in your head before posting a new question. I'm happy to help, but I'm fat, so I'm loathe to jump through rings.